# If clause does not change output after repeated test cases in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I have the following scenario: I have to write a code in Python based on that rock-paper-scissors-lizard-Spock game of The Big Bang Theory. I thought I had gotten the structure of the code quite correctly, but when it came to testing, I tried to make a win-lose-tie scenario by entering 3 for the number of test cases, then "paper rock" for the first round, "lizard scissors" for the second and "Spock Spock" for the third. The problem is that the expected outcome was supposed to be win - lose - tie, but in all of them the output was win. Could anyone help me finding out what am I missing here? Thanks!

```
T = int(input("Enter the number of desired test cases from 1 to 100: "))

Win = Lose = Tie = False

for i in range(T):
    Sheldon, Raj = input("Enter Sheldon's and Raj's plays: ").split(' ')

    if(Sheldon == Raj):
        Tie = True
    elif((Sheldon == "rock" and (Raj in ["scissors","lizard"])) or
         (Sheldon == "paper" and (Raj in ["rock","Spock"])) or
         (Sheldon == "scissors" and (Raj in ["paper","lizard"])) or
         (Sheldon == "Spock" and (Raj in ["rock","scissors"])) or
         (Sheldon == "lizard" and (Raj in ["paper","Spock"]))
        ):
        Win = True
    else:
        Lose = True

    if(Win == True):
        print("Case #{0}: Bazinga!".format(i+1))
    elif(Lose == True):
        print("Case #{0}: Raj cheated!".format(i+1))
    elif(Tie == True):
        print("Case #{0}: Again!".format(i+1))
```

Comment: Because you never reset `Win` to `False` between turns, so once `True`, it will remain `True`. Include `Win = Lose = Tie = False` at the start of the loop.

Comment: As a side note, the very well respected convention in Python is to use lowercase for variables, and capitalized names only for classes. And you don't need parentheses around the condition after `if`, and `if win == True:` is simply written `if win:`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Didn't know about this convention, I'm gonna change the code accordingly. Thanks for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make all(Win, lose and Tie) = False at the end of every iteration so that loop will start fresh every time.

And you can use if(Win) instead of if(Win == True) because if statement will only execute when the condition is True.

```
T = int(input("Enter the number of desired test cases from 1 to 100: "))

Win = Lose = Tie = False
for i in range(T):
    Sheldon, Raj = input("Enter Sheldon's and Raj's plays: ").split(' ')

    if(Sheldon == Raj):
        Tie = True
    elif((Sheldon == "rock" and (Raj in ["scissors","lizard"])) or
         (Sheldon == "paper" and (Raj in ["rock","Spock"])) or
         (Sheldon == "scissors" and (Raj in ["paper","lizard"])) or
         (Sheldon == "Spock" and (Raj in ["rock","scissors"])) or
         (Sheldon == "lizard" and (Raj in ["paper","Spock"]))):
        Win = True
    else:
        Lose = True

    if(Win):
        print("Case #{0}: Bazinga!".format(i+1))
    elif(Lose):
        print("Case #{0}: Raj cheated!".format(i+1))
    elif(Tie):
        print("Case #{0}: Again!".format(i+1))

    # Again make all false on each iteration
    Win = Lose = Tie = False
```